# Celery consumer connection to broker (rabbitmq) lost

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp, kombu

I have celery running in kubernetes pod. The command which I use to run celery is `celery -A mycelery worker --time-limit 14400 -c 8 -Q myqueue1,myqueue2 --hostname mycelery_auto_worker@%h --loglevel INFO`, and the installed packages are as below.

```
amqp==5.1.1
async-timeout==4.0.2
billiard==3.6.4.0
celery==5.2.7
certifi==2022.9.14
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
croniter==1.3.7
cryptography==38.0.1
Deprecated==1.2.13
docker==4.3.0
elastic-enterprise-search==7.14.0
elastic-transport==7.16.0
idna==3.4
kombu==5.2.4
ldap3==2.9.1
marshmallow==2.20.5
mongoengine==0.24.2
mysqlclient==2.0.1
netaddr==0.8.0
packaging==21.3
prettytable==3.4.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.31
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.5.0
pymongo==4.2.0
pymsteams==0.2.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.2.1
PyU4V==10.0.0.16
redis==4.3.4
requests==2.28.1
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.12
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
websocket-client==1.4.1
wrapt==1.14.1
```

Its working fine, but in between, it loose connection and gives error for connection time out as below.

```
2022-09-23T08:16:57.086066685-04:00 stderr F [2022-09-23 12:16:57,085: INFO/MainProcess] missed heartbeat from myworker1@a0b963a2e03f
2022-09-23T08:16:57.086119393-04:00 stderr F [2022-09-23 12:16:57,086: INFO/MainProcess] missed heartbeat from myworker2@3312756a8f0d
2022-09-23T08:17:09.05803789-04:00 stderr F [2022-09-23 12:17:09,054: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058110205-04:00 stderr F Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058118751-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 332, in start
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058124009-04:00 stderr F     blueprint.start(self)
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058128801-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058133403-04:00 stderr F     step.start(parent)
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058137355-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 628, in start
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058141089-04:00 stderr F     c.loop(*c.loop_args())
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058145102-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 97, in asynloop
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058150138-04:00 stderr F     next(loop)
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058153921-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py", line 362, in create_loop
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058157717-04:00 stderr F     cb(*cbargs)
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058161636-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 235, in on_readable
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058165427-04:00 stderr F     reader(loop)
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058169378-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 217, in _read
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058174718-04:00 stderr F     drain_events(timeout=0)
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058178592-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 525, in drain_events
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058182378-04:00 stderr F     while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058186046-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 530, in blocking_read
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058189642-04:00 stderr F     frame = self.transport.read_frame()
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058193507-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 294, in read_frame
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058197122-04:00 stderr F     frame_header = read(7, True)
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058218305-04:00 stderr F   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 627, in _read
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058222178-04:00 stderr F     s = recv(n - len(rbuf))
2022-09-23T08:17:09.058225496-04:00 stderr F TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

After this, there is warning related to `late acknowledge task` as below.

```
2022-09-26T10:49:18.975973308Z stderr F [2022-09-26 10:49:18,975: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:367: CPendingDeprecationWarning:
2022-09-26T10:49:18.976021014Z stderr F In Celery 5.1 we introduced an optional breaking change which
2022-09-26T10:49:18.976034128Z stderr F on connection loss cancels all currently executed tasks with late acknowledgement enabled.
2022-09-26T10:49:18.976043266Z stderr F These tasks cannot be acknowledged as the connection is gone, and the tasks are automatically redelivered back to the queue.
2022-09-26T10:49:18.976052858Z stderr F You can enable this behavior using the worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss setting.
2022-09-26T10:49:18.976060383Z stderr F In Celery 5.1 it is set to False by default. The setting will be set to True by default in Celery 6.0.
```

I already set the `broker_transport_options` as below.

```
broker_connection_timeout = 10.0
broker_transport_options = {
    "max_retries": 3,
    "interval_start": 0,
    "interval_step": 0.2,
    "interval_max": 0.5,
    "retry_policy": {
        "timeout": 5.0
    }
}
```

but still it not help. I check the rabbitmq logs, but that also not give proper answer, it has some errors as `client unexpectedly closed TCP connection`, but not sure, that might be the cause of this consumer connection lost.

```
2022-09-23 20:20:44.339 [warning] <0.11840.2379> closing AMQP connection <0.11840.2379> (10.4.106.3:40596 -> 172.17.102.130:5672, vhost: 'my-vhost', user: 'my-vhost'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
2022-09-23 20:20:44.710 [warning] <0.3980.2377> closing AMQP connection <0.3980.2377> (10.15.192.78:53718 -> 172.17.102.130:5672, vhost: 'my-vhost', user: 'my-vhost'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
2022-09-23 20:20:44.934 [warning] <0.19511.2380> closing AMQP connection <0.19511.2380> (10.15.192.90:40776 -> 172.17.102.130:5672, vhost: 'my-vhost', user: 'my-vhost'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
2022-09-23 20:20:45.577 [warning] <0.8721.2386> closing AMQP connection <0.8721.2386> (10.15.192.83:41954 -> 172.17.102.130:5672, vhost: 'my-vhost', user: 'my-vhost'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
2022-09-23 20:20:51.147 [info] <0.23491.2386> accepting AMQP connection <0.23491.2386> (10.4.106.3:39168 -> 172.17.102.130:5672)
2022-09-23 20:20:51.150 [info] <0.23491.2386> connection <0.23491.2386> (10.4.106.3:39168 -> 172.17.102.130:5672): user 'my-vhost' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'my-vhost'
2022-09-23 20:20:52.955 [info] <0.18223.2385> accepting AMQP connection <0.18223.2385> (10.4.106.3:51670 -> 172.17.102.130:5672)
2022-09-23 20:20:52.959 [info] <0.18223.2385> connection <0.18223.2385> (10.4.106.3:51670 -> 172.17.102.130:5672): user 'my-vhost' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'my-vhost'
2022-09-23 20:21:05.505 [warning] <0.6386.2362> closing AMQP connection <0.6386.2362> (10.15.192.79:40658 -> 172.17.102.130:5672, vhost: 'my-vhost', user: 'my-vhost'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

Is there any other way to retry connection? when connection lost, let me know.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on here, @Nilesh?

Comment: No, I didn't figure out, but now with retry logic, works, it failed to connect and next seconds its connect to rabbitmq again. Not seeing the send message failure.